# Set immutable bit for specified time

Tags: linux, xattr

It's possible to set immutable bit for a specified range of days?

I was trying to understand how Veeam11 can change the attribute after a few days for immutable backup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps

```
echo 'chattr +i filename' | at beginning_timestamp
echo 'chattr -i filename' | at ending_timestamp
```

Would this work for you?